# SSH tunnel to database server over multiple hops

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

SSH tunneling is easy to accomplish:

```
ssh -D1234 host
```

But we have a more specific infrastructure

- `Host 1` (Remote server placed in my company)
- `Host 2` (Local server inside `Host 1` network)
- `Host 3` (External DB server in another country)

Host 3 is only accessible from host 2, and host 2 is only accessible from host 1.

So, I need an ssh tunnel solution to access the database server on my laptop directly from any database management software over port 3306.

Note that there are a lot of articles about proxy and jump ssh, but I don’t need a temporary SSH session in the terminal, but a tunnel to stay open while I'm using the port outside the terminal (i.g., DB management software).

Comment: I assume you can’t install a VPN on host 2? Does host 2 have a proxy server running on it?

Comment: It does have one which we connect to through Host 3 (knowing that this VPN cannot be run out side Host 2)

Comment: As long as Host 1, can connect to the VPN running on Host 2, and the VPN has a route to Host 3 a setup like that should work.

Comment: Wouldn't `ssh -J user1@host1,user2@host2 -D1234 user3@host3` work? (Or maybe replace `-D1234` with whatever the appropriate tunnel option is.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson It seems working on this port, but what if the port in Host 3 is `3306` (MySQL port) and I want it to be mirrored/tunneled to Host 2 and Host 1 on port let's say `6789`? So I can access the DB using the new port

Comment: Because I'm getting this error when connecting ```bind [127.0.0.1]:3306: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3306
Could not request local forwarding.``` ...... I guess port 3306 is already used in Host 2 so I can’t use it

Comment: Using `-J`, you skip using ports on the intermediate hosts, so TCP forwarding just runs between the local and final hosts (just like it would if there were no intermediate hops involved). Now, I'm confused by your description. Is the DB server on your laptop and you want client software on host 3 to be able to connect to it, or is the server on host 3 and you want client software on your laptop to access it?

Comment: DB is on Host 3, and I just noticed that I have MySQL installed and running on my own machine that's why I need a solution to change the port when it's received (to not conflict with my open ports locally)

Comment: @GordonDavisson also, I tried to connect to a web server that I created in the DB server, and it did response from inside my company's PC, but from my mac it showed this msg in the browser: "This page isn’t working ... localhost didn’t send any data .... ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE", even MySQL server I stopped it on my mac and tried but stuck in the terminal without response

Comment: Try `ssh -J user1@host1,user2@host2 -L 6789:127.0.0.1:3306 user3@host3`, and then have the DB client on your local machine connect to 127.0.0.1:6789.